# Cannot PubSub from Mongo Db Atlas function

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, mongodb-atlas

[image]I am using the following Code to do a simple pubsub from a MongoDB function to Google Pubsub.
But when I instantiate PubSub : const pubSubClient = new PubSub(); I get TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined. Any hint on how to solve this issue?

```
exports = function(changeEvent) {
      
    const topicName = 'topicname';
    const data = JSON.stringify({foo: 'bar'});
    
    const {PubSub} = require('pubsub');
    
    const pubSubClient = new PubSub();
    
   async function publishMessageWithCustomAttributes() {
  // Publishes the message as a string, e.g. "Hello, world!" or JSON.stringify(someObject)
  const dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);

  // Add two custom attributes, origin and username, to the message
  const customAttributes = {
    origin: 'nodejs-sample',
    username: 'gcp',
  };

  const messageId = await pubSubClient
    .topic(topicName)
    .publish(dataBuffer, customAttributes);
  console.log(`Message ${messageId} published.`);
}

publishMessageWithCustomAttributes().catch(console.error);

};
```

Comment: Could you share your complete code and the full log stack traces as it will help to replicate and troubleshoot the issue better.

Comment: I have added the full code of the function that is called by a database insert trigger. As regards the errors this is the only message that I get: TypeError: Value is not an object: undefined. And it seems to be triggered by : const pubSubClient = new PubSub();

Comment: Hi, could you try to change the ```const {PubSub} = require('pubsub')``` to ```const {PubSub} = require('@google-cloud/pubsub')``` as per the pub/sub docs, as ```@google-cloud/pubsub``` is the Google Cloud client library and for more information you can refer to this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library) guide.

Comment: I tried and it tells me Cannot find module '@google-cloud/pubsub'. From the dependencies I have imported pubsub but maybe it is not the google library. The problem is it does not find any other pubsub library.

Comment: Could you refer to the quickstart link i have shared and import the client library given in that doc i.e ```npm install --save @google-cloud/pubsub```

Comment: I managed to include the library. I run the function again and I get: > ran at Fri Feb 04 2022 14:42:02 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
> took 11.862096935s
> error logs: 
Error: exec is not supported
> result: 
{
  "$undefined": true
}
> result (JavaScript): 
EJSON.parse('{"$undefined":true}')